# Angularjs: select not working when ng-model a json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Once I use `ng-options` for a select I am unable to get dafault selection to work on nested json objects.

once I have a bit more complicated json and the select should handle a child object my select does not default select the proper value.

Given `test = {"id":3,"title":"Test","product":{"id":4,"name":"Test1"}}` as my `ng-model test.product` and 

    `[{
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Test1"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Test2"
    }]`

as my selection option. (see http://embed.plnkr.co/mpnislw77UBSEdHl4UKN/)
I seem to be unable to figure out how to facilitate default selection.

---

If you use track by item.id it works - http://embed.plnkr.co/mpnislw77UBSEdHl4UKN. The marked answer was not very obious since the ng-model is nested in iself. but it contains the correct information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to select with ngOptions and setting a default value

**Example**

```js
angular.module('defaultValueSelect', [])
 .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.data = {
    availableOptions: [
      {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
      {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
      {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
    ],
    selectedOption: {id: '3', name: 'Option C'} //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
    };
}]);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="defaultValueSelect">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="mySelect">Make a choice:</label>
    <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
      ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id"
      ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>option = {{data.selectedOption}}</tt><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you use track by item.id it works - embed.plnkr.co/mpnislw77UBSEdHl4UKN. Your answer was not very obious since the ng-model is nested in iself. but it contains the correct information.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with your code is that you've assigned a new object to `$scope.test.product` and you're using it as the `ng-model` of the dropdown.

This makes AngularJS unable to find it inside the possible values, which are `$scope.testarray`. AngularJS will compare two objects by their reference, which you broke when you assigned a new object to `$scope.test.product`.

To make it working, change `$scope.test` as follows:

```
$scope.test = {
  "id": 3,
  "title": "Test",
  "product": $scope.testarray[1]
}
```

Comment: what if both test and testarray are retirved from the db. Can I trick it to check on value isntead of reference?

Comment: @user3400965 --  `ng-model` should have the reference to one of the objects of `ng-options` if you've `item` as an object. You have to find the object in the array first, and then assign it to `ng-model` in case you're fetching it from DB.

Comment: If you use  track by item.id it works - https://embed.plnkr.co/mpnislw77UBSEdHl4UKN/. I like ur answer though

Comment: @user3400965 -- it works because `id` is a primitive data type (number) and isn't compared by reference, but by value.

Answer (score 0):

try this, hope it will help

```
 <option value="" ng-if="false"></option>
```

Comment: Whilst a valid answer, this is incomplete. It could use the OP's test data or plunker to make the answer more clear.